# How to pass control's ID into an external javascript file?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to call an **External JavaScript Function** that accept 3 parameters as below:

```
function CalculateSum(grdID, hiddenID, TargetColumnIndex) {
    debugger;
    var oDataGrid = document.getElementById("<%= grdID.ClientID %>");
    var tableRows = oDataGrid.rows;
    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = 1; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
        var col1 = oDataGrid.rows[i].cells[TargetColumnIndex];
        for (j = 0; j < col1.childNodes.length; j++) {
            if (col1.childNodes[j].type == "text") {
                if (!isNaN(col1.childNodes[j].value) && col1.childNodes[j].value != "") {
                    sum += parseInt(col1.childNodes[j].value)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (!isNaN(sum)) {
        document.getElementById('<%=hiddenID.ClientID %>').value = sum;
    }
}
```

And this is how i did call it:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" 
    OnClientClick="CalculateSum('grdPlanObjectivesStandardWeights', '#hidden', 2);" 
    OnClick="btnSave_Click" 
    Text="<%$Resources:DCAACommon, Save%>" 
    ValidationGroup="SaveStandardWeight" />
```

**Notes:**

- When i run this code i have an error says: `'CalculateSum' is undefined`.
- The parameters i'm trying to pass are:

  `grdPlanObjectivesStandardWeights` is a `asp:GridViewID`.

  `hidden` is a `asp:HiddenFieldID`.

  `2` is an int value.
- I can't even debug this function.
- The function defined here: `<script src="../../Common/Scripts/SummationOfAGridviewColumnValues.js"></script>`

What is wrong with my code/approach?

Comment: check if you are properly including the javascript file in the head of the page or not.

Comment: I should've mention before .. the JS file included properly.

Comment: As well as Manish's point, make sure the method is visible to the page. It might be hidden inside something incorrectly, if you have completed Manish's point. Another check is to have <script>alert(CalculateSum);</script> at the bottom of your page. If it displays your function, then it is included correctly. Otherwise it isn't or isn't visible to the calling method.

Comment: @VDWWD Insted of editing my question( deleting 2 characters in body) ,you should've vote it up as a **clear** question.!!

Comment: You are absolutely right. I forgot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to send the aspnet Control ID's as variable client-side, and then using them with `ClientID`.

You either don't send the ID's as variable, but just use the aspnet ID with ClientID

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>

<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function CalculateSum(TargetColumnIndex) {
        var oDataGrid = document.getElementById("<%= GridView1.ClientID %>");

        if (!isNaN(sum)) {
            document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>').value = sum;
            }
        }
</script>
```

Or send the correct ID's to the function, but then you won't need `<%= GridView1.ClientID %>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    CalculateSum("<%= GridView1.ClientID %>", "<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>", 2)

    function CalculateSum(grdID, hiddenID, TargetColumnIndex) {
        var oDataGrid = document.getElementById(grdID);

        if (!isNaN(sum)) {
            document.getElementById(hiddenID).value = sum;
            }
        }
</script>
```

Or call from code behind

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "CalculateSum", "CalculateSum('" + GridView1.ClientID + "', '" + HiddenField1.ClientID + "', 2)", true);
```

> Note that `<%= GridView1.ClientID %>` will not work in an external file,
>   so the second option would be better. Of coure `CalculateSum("<%= GridView1.ClientID %>", "<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>", 2)` should then be placed on the aspx page.

Comment: I can't use the first approach since i'm using an external JS file function, but i will try the second one and return with feed back soon

Comment: You can also call from code behind. I've added a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

From your markup it appears you are working with asp.net MVC, or at least asp.net. If this is the case you need to register your script.

Something like the following should work:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"CallMyFunction","MyFunction()",true);
```

You can find out more [at this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx)

To expand upon my answer. In your web form code behind, place thee following in the Page_Load method:

```
Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("MyScript",
   "<script language=javascript src='MyJavaScriptFile.js'>");
```

You should then be able to reference your JS functions

Comment: I'm using ASP.net webforms. can't you be more specific ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered trying to set `ClientIdMode="Static"` for your controls and just reference the id names as is?

Comment: Basically your gridview adds in the ClientIDMode attribute <asp:gridview runat="server" id="grdPlanObjectivesStandardWeights" ClientIDMode="Static"...> and then you should be able to refrence it from client side JS as document.getElementById("grdPlanObjectivesStandardWeights"); ...no need for script reference. You can also do for your hidden control (add ClientIDMode)